# How to get the difference between 2 times in SSRS

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I want to get the difference between 2 columns that have a time datatype in SSRS

```
FormatDateTime(dateadd(DateInterval.Minute, datediff(DateInterval.Minute, Fields!TimeFrom.Value, Fields!TimeTo.Value), 0) ,"hh:mm")
```

I tried this but it didn't work and is there a way to sum it up ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom code for it. You can refer this article for more detail about it.

[Using custome code in SSRS](https://www.interfacett.com/blogs/using-custom-code-ssrs/)

The following custom code will be help to handle your issue

```
Public Function GetFormatedTime(byval dblSeconds as double) as String
   Dim result as String
    Dim Hours, Minutes, Seconds As Integer
Seconds = dblSeconds 
Hours = Seconds / 3600
        Seconds = Seconds Mod 3600
        Minutes = Seconds / 60
        Seconds = Seconds Mod 60
result=Hours.ToString.PadLeft(2, "0"c) & ":" & Minutes.ToString.PadLeft(2, "0"c) & ":" & Seconds.ToString.PadLeft(2, "0"c)

   return result
End Function
```

This function takes second as parameter. For example ;

```
code.GetFormatedTime(3699)
```

expresion returns

```
01:02:09
```